# On RHEL8 how can I use `alternatives` to choose an already listed version as the used version

Tags: rhel, python3, alternatives

On a RHEL 8.3 system I have two python3 versions installed and they show up as the version when I list alterantives' versions:

```
$ alternatives --display python3

/usr/bin/python3.6 - priority 1000000
 slave easy_install-3: /usr/bin/easy_install-3.6
 slave pip-3: /usr/bin/pip-3.6
 slave pip3: /usr/bin/pip3.6
 slave pydoc-3: /usr/bin/pydoc3.6
 slave pydoc3: /usr/bin/pydoc3.6
 slave pyvenv-3: /usr/bin/pyvenv-3.6
 slave python3-man: /usr/share/man/man1/python3.6.1.gz
/usr/bin/python3.9 - priority 3900
 slave easy_install-3: /usr/bin/easy_install-3.9
 slave pip-3: /usr/bin/pip-3.9
 slave pip3: /usr/bin/pip3.9
 slave pydoc-3: /usr/bin/pydoc3.9
 slave pydoc3: /usr/bin/pydoc3.9
 slave pyvenv-3: (null)
 slave python3-man: /usr/share/man/man1/python3.9.1.gz
Current `best' version is /usr/bin/python3.6.
```

How can I use the `alternatives` command to choose the already listed `python3.9` as the used version? (I.e. system-wide I want to execute `python3.9` when I type on the command line `python3`).

*Note:* I understand I can add a *new* version with `alternatives --install` (and then make it the best one with a high priority), but how can I *choose* an already listed version as the best (and used) one?

Comment: Please note that several system libraries are linked to python3.6. That's the same as `/usr/libexec/platform-python`. If you want to script system administration on RHEL8, then rather stick to 3.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
alternatives --config python3
```

will display a list of installed `python3` releases and you can choose which to use.  Note that this will lock you to that selection.  Installing a new higher release will not automatically be used by the system.

```
alternatives --auto python3
```

will reset the `--config` so the system will use what it considers the best release automatically when new releases are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that if you want to set python3 version in batch script without interactive promt, you may use command

```
alternatives --set python3 /usr/bin/python3.9
```

And optionally

```
alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.9
```